# XPath: Query a node's children XOR a subnode's children if subnode is present

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm attempting to find all of the direct children of a specific node **A** *xor* -- if and only if **B** is present as a child of **A** -- the direct children of **B**. I'm stumped!

(**A** and **B** represent specific elements; say `<body/>` and `<article/>`)

---

In another way:

If a certain element **B** is a child of **A**, find children of **B** instead of **A**. Otherwise, just return the children of **A**.

---

Or, still another way:

```
A > c c c c c c...
A > B > c c c c c c...
```

I want to get `[c, c, c, c, c, c, ...]` regardless of whether **B** is present. I'm essentially wanting to "skip a level" if said level appears in the DOM. Please suggest a method.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question would be easier to follow if you provided specific examples of XML and specific examples of what should be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two XPath 1.0-compatible examples:

You could do so like this:

```
(/parent/container/a[not(b)] | /parent/container/a/b)/*
```

Or to use the double-slash syntax (which I would recommend avoiding unless the paths are really long):

```
(//a[not(b)] | //a/b)/*
```

But since your question is tagged with XPath 2.0, the following would probably be more efficient than either of those:

```
/parent/container/a/(if (b) then b/* else *)
```

Example input:

```
<parent>
  <container>
    <a>
      <c>1</c>
      <c>2</c>
    </a>
  </container>
  <container>
    <a>
      <c>3</c>
      <b>
        <c>4</c>
        <c>5</c>
      </b>
      <b>
        <c>6</c>
      </b>
      <c>7</c>
    </a>
  </container>
  <container>
    <a>
      <c>8</c>
    </a>
  </container>
</parent>
```

When run with any of the above paths, the result is:

```
<c>1</c>
<c>2</c>
<c>4</c>
<c>5</c>
<c>6</c>
<c>8</c>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[not(child::b)]/child::* | //b[parent::a]/child::*
```

Comment: The explicit `child::` axis is unnecessary.